# Can't get malloc debug to turn on?

Tags: android, android-ndk

I'm trying to enable malloc debug for my android application, and for the life of me i can't get it working.

My `wrap.sh` scripts each contain this:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
LIBC_DEBUG_MALLOC_OPTIONS="free-track verbose"
logwrapper "$@"
```

and I've set up the following directory structure:

[image: directory structure]

When I grep logcat for "malloc debug enabled", I get nothing.

If i change my `wrap.sh` scripts contents to this

```
#!/system/bin/sh
LIBC_DEBUG_MALLOC_OPTIONS=free-track logwrapper "$@"
```

which is exactly what [the documentation for the wrap shell script](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/wrap-script.html#malloc_debug) says to add (although to me that seems like invalid shell script syntax), i can see the "malloc debug enabled" log message, but my application freezes at the splash screen and never actually launches.

I'm not sure what's going on and would love any type of input.

**Other notes:**

- My project is using CMake.
- My debug device is running Android P.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is for running an executable binary on Android. I think you are running a Java app with JNI calls, and that trick does not apply to you. You will have to set those environment variables from JAVA as the app starts.

Try looking at `OS.setenv()` - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html. I hope that those environment variables can be set from Java before the JNI library is loaded, or that the library reads those environment variables on every call, and not just init.

Answer (score 0):

If the accepted answer doesn't work for you then my solution might work:

```
#!/system/bin/sh
LIBC_DEBUG_MALLOC_OPTIONS=free-track logwrapper
exec "$@"
```

Make sure line endings are LF and not CRLF.

Then my issue was that malloc debug wasn't able to write the dump:

```
E/malloc_debug: Unable to create file: /data/local/tmp/backtrace_heap.16934.exit.txt
```

I thought this might be due missing permissions. By changing the output folder to the one of your app, this is circumvented:

```
LIBC_DEBUG_MALLOC_OPTIONS='backtrace backtrace_dump_on_exit backtrace_dump_prefix=data/data/com.your.app/files/dump' logwrapper
```

And dumping now works:

```
E/malloc_debug: Dumping to file: data/data/com.your.app/files/dump.17599.exit.txt
```

Also make sure you set

```
buildTypes{
debug {
            debuggable true
        }
}
```

in build.gradle and

```
android:extractNativeLibs="true"
android:debuggable="true"
```

in the AndroidManifest.xml file